# Filter all lines that contain words with two vowels (grep)?

Tags: regex, linux, grep

I want to use grep to sort all lines from a file that contain any two vowels one after each other.
For example if I have the next file

```
aab aeb baaa
eg gefee xxe
xx a axa
```

I want to keep only the first two lines because they contain 2 vowels. I just can't figure out the right regular expression for this. It should work with any combination (aa, ae, ai, ao, .., ee etc)

Comment: How do you define vocals?

Comment: translated it wrong I'm talking about vowels

Comment: nevermind, I figured it out. Sometimes I'm... stupid...

Answer (score 2):

Depending on which letters count as vowels in your language, something like

```
[aeiou][aeiou]
```

If you have graphemes which are only sometimes vocalic (like *y* in English -- a vowel in "try" but a consonant in "yet") you will need something singnificantly more sophisticated; from your examples, it looks like maybe this is sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

For the data set in your example, the following `grep` command will give you the results you are looking for:

```
grep -e ".*[aeiou][aeiou].*" foo.txt
aab aeb baaa
eg gefee xxe
```

Comment: The leading and trailing `.*` are superfluous; `grep` looks for a match anywhere on the line.

Comment: @tripleee - That is correct;  just coded it that way to show explicitly that there might be other characters before and after the contiguous vowels.  But you are right, if you try `grep -e "[aeiou][aeiou]" foo.txt` it works the same.  Thanks for pointing that out :-)